# Http live streaming: Forcing MPMoviePlayerController to pack headers in the http requests

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, http-live-streaming

I am streaming video from a server to iPhone using Http Live Streaming. I need to set certain headers in the http packets that the phone sends to the server.

For regular packets, the following code would suffice:

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url]
                                autorelease];
[request setValue:VALUE forHTTPHeaderField:@"Field You Want To Set"];
```

Unfortunately, I did not find a similar API for `MPMoviePlayerController`. In other words, how do I force `MPMoviePlayerController` to set certain headers in the http packets that it uses to communicate to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think setting a cookie might solve your problem. Please look into the documentation for NSHTTPCookie and NSHTTPCookieStorage.

Comment: +1 for suggesting a next-best workaround. However, I am still curious to find a solution that does not involve the server setting cookies proactively.

Comment: I was able to accomplish this with a custom NSURLProtocol. Check out my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24098761/107821

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll find a solution other than using NSHTTPCookieStorage to have the client send cookie based headers to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I had this problem too, and found from stack overflow that the solution is to use NSURLProtocol. Still, it was painful figuring out how to do it, so I thought I'd save people some time by sharing the coded solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23261001/3547099