# iOS > v10.0 devices not playing videos from a CloudFront distribution using signed cookies

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, video, cookies, amazon-cloudfront

**UPDATE**: The problem is with playing HTML5 videos in Safari not with playing videos in a native application.

Since v10.0 upgrade iOS devices cannot play videos from a CloudFront distribution with signed cookies restriction enabled.

If I disable signed cookies restriction it works as it does with previous iOS versions.

I've checked the release notes and checked each related forum seeking for an explanation and ideally a solution for this issue. I found nothing reported in either Apple nor AWS/CloudFront's official forums.

Is anyone experiencing this very issue as well? Or even better, is anyone getting iOS v10 devices play videos using CloudFront with signed cookies restriction?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify how you're setting the headers on the requests? Are you following this example of using a custom URL protocol with the player class?

[How to insert header info into MPMoviePlayerController url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027628/how-to-insert-header-info-into-mpmovieplayercontroller-url)

thanks,
Andrew C

Comment: Now I see I didn't specify the problem is with Safari not with native apps.