# Amazon Cloudfront Issue in iOS 10

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

We use Amazon Cloudfront to serve static content. We now find, that users who upgraded to iOS 10, **AND** who are connected via public wifi (optimumwifi), get a 502 error for any Cloudfront page. The error message is as follows:

> Cloudfront attempted to establish a connection with the origin, but
>   either the attempt failed or the origin closed the connection.

This is a false message for 2 reasons, as the origin **is** reachable, and as the Cloudfront page **is** reachable from all other device or when using private wifi. In addition, there is no reason that Cloudfront should be attempting to get the origin, as the page should be cached already, and it should be serving the cached version.
I have found a similiar post at [iOS > v10.0 devices not playing videos from a CloudFront distribution using signed cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40379290/ios-v10-0-devices-not-playing-videos-from-a-cloudfront-distribution-using-sign) , but we do not use any cookies, so that shouldn't be the issue.
This issue happens when calling the page from Safari, both http and https. You can test the issue at the following link: http://d1286uoz7ltgna.cloudfront.net/lion.jpg, which will work from most devices, but not on iOS 10 when on optimumwifi. I hope anyone out there has a solution for this wierd issue.

Comment: *"In addition, there is no reason that Cloudfront should be attempting to get the origin, as the page should be cached already"*  You have no way of knowing that, unless you know *which* CloudFront edge the request is arriving at (and technically, not even then).  Objects are only cached at the edges through which they are being requested, and this provider's IP address space may be geolocating in such a way that the requests arrive at an unexpected edge.  Have you reviewed the logs from your CloudFront distribution to see where these requests are arriving?

Comment: Additionally does this problem only occur with the optimumwifi service or any public wifi?

Comment: I didn't check, but we have multiple devices on same network and location, and it's always the iOS with the issue. In addition we are hearing from complaints from our customers who are using iOS. As for if it's only optimum wifi or all public wifi, we are not sure, as we only have access to optimumwifi. I'm not sure which one our users were using. It does work on regular Optimum internet, so it is an issue only on their public wifi.

Comment: Do you have the x-amz-cf-id response header when there is an error?

Comment: Where do I get that from?

Comment: I have been contacted by Amazon support within the hour (they must have some respect for StackOverflow!). I will update here when solved. Thanks.