# MPMoviePlayerViewController remove "Audio and Subtitles" control

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am playing a live stream video with `MPMoviePlayerViewController` and I want to disable the bottom right button for "Audio and Subtitles".  The only solution I have found for this is to set the `moviePlayer.controlStyle` property to `MPMovieControlStyleNone`, but that hides all the controls.

Is there any way to customize a `MPMoviePlayerViewController` to hide the subtitles button?

Comment: Did you succeeded hiding this control ?

Comment: Not yet, I haven't figured out how to insert http headers for a url.. I will mark your answer as correct if you can update it with this information.. thank you!

Comment: I've updated my answer, hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the reason why the button is there, and the way to hide it :

[Video Player unexpectedly shows Alternate Track button for Subtitles and Captions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1801/_index.html)

> The source material will have to include: CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE on the EXT-X-STREAM-INF tag to remove the Button.

**Edit :**

I've been searching on *"how to insert HTTP headers for a URL"* and found a few interesting results. First, if you really want to insert HTTP headers to your URL, the following might do the job :

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setValue:@"NONE" forHTTPHeaderField:@"CLOSED-CAPTIONS"];
```

If it's not what you're searching for, the solution [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6770974/4894980) could make the job :

> I think setting a cookie might solve your problem. Please look into the documentation for NSHTTPCookie and NSHTTPCookieStorage.

If it's still not working, take a look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027628/how-to-insert-header-info-into-mpmovieplayercontroller-url/24098761#24098761).

Finally, if all those steps didn't help, implement your own control bar [thanks to this tutorial](https://wosimei.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/how-to-custom-a-ios-movie-player-control-bar/).

Comment: Glad to know you've succeeded :)